# I examined every little piece of information and I still didn't find my goal. I am always trying to improve but in this situation I simply can't

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and I am asking how to find this very specific example that I want to post. It is very frustrating and disturbing. I have been trying to figure this out, but it didn't work out. A specific one example is "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

```
-- Corporate 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO branch VALUES(1, 'Corporate', 100, '2006-02-09');

UPDATE employee
SET branch_id = 1
WHERE emp_id = 100,

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(101, 'Jan', 'Levinson', 1961-05-11', 'F', 110000, 100, 1);
```

The error I am getting is:
ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: If you don't specify the columns to insert then the number of values have to be the same as the number of columns in the table. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Always specify the column names on an `INSERT`. For example: `INSERT INTO employee (ID, SALARY) VALUES (1, 150)`.

Comment: After two hours without any clarification I'm voting to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am very new to learning MySQL and having lot of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394224/i-am-very-new-to-learning-mysql-and-having-lot-of-problems)