# What does the MySQL mean by "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, create-table

This is the message I'm getting

> ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This is my whole code. Where is my mistake?

```
DROP TABLE student;

CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first-name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  SALARY INT,
  super_id INT,
  branch_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE branch (
  branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_name VARCHAR(40),
  mgr_id INT,
  mgr_start_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE works_with (
  emp_id INT,
  client_id INT,
  total_sales INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, client_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Corporate
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO branch VALUES(1, 'Corporate', 100, '2006-02-09');

UPDATE employee
SET branch_id = 1
WHERE employee_id = 100;

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(101, 'Jan', 'Levinson', '1961-05-11', 'F', 110000, 100, 1);
```

Comment: You're trying to insert 8 values into a table with 7 columns

Comment: You already asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386159/i-examined-every-little-piece-of-information-and-i-still-didnt-find-my-goal-i You should edit the first question with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `employee` table has 7 columns, but you are giving 8 values for insert, which generates the error message that you are getting.

A good habit is to list the columns for `insert` in the statement. This makes this type of error much easier to spot, since you don't need to look back at the definition of the table (it also prevents your query from failing if you ever add new columns to the table at some point in the future - or drop existing columns).

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, first_name, birth_day, sex, salary, super_id, branch_id)
VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL);
```

Side note: unquoted identifier `first-name`, that can be seen in the `create table` statement for `employee`, is not valid - because it contains a dash (`-`). I assume that's a typo and you meant an underscore instead (`first_name`).

Comment: I am very new to coding. Can you explain in a way I can understand what you are trying to say? I am only nine years old and don't know much about coding.